# how to make the button to have a value (id) so whenever user clicks a button, I want to trigger an function with id

Tags: angularjs

I want buttons to have **id** so I can do something whenever the button is clicked. How can I do this? 
do I have to bind with *ng-model* or how can I pass the value(id) when clicked?

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="field in availableFields">
    <td style="padding:3px;">{{field.name}}</td>
    <td style="padding:3px;">
    <button type="button" ng-model="" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-left:10px;"><i class="fas fa- 
   check"></i>&nbsp;Required</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fas fa-check"> 
   </i>&nbsp;Default&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `ng-model` with button elements. Since you are inside `ng-repeat`, you can use `$index` or a field property (like field.id) and pass it in `ng-click` function:

```
<tr ng-repeat="field in availableFields">
    <td style="padding:3px;">{{field.name}}</td>
    <td style="padding:3px;">
    <button type="button" ng-click="onClick($index)" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-left:10px;"><i class="fas fa- 
   check"></i>&nbsp;Required</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fas fa-check"> 
   </i>&nbsp;Default&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```